# Center image based on size inside div with whitespace

Tags: css, html

I am jumping into a large complex application today and it's a bit daunting.

So, I want to solve the issue locally then find where the solution should eventually be located.

I have square images that come from sources of various sizes. Currently the image fills the div regardless of its dimensions.

[image]

```
<li class="hint-li" data-position="undefined" data-id="551ef3279934asda2e2565" id="551efsfasd8354582e2565" style="background-image: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/source/558dadasd9a0f3.616asd74.jpg);">
  <div class="sold-out hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="partnered hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <strong>
          Thermal bath, aromatherapy, massage
        </strong>
        <em>
          Aire Ancient Bath
        </em>
        <strong class="hintPrice">
          $181
        </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <a target="_blank" class="buy" href="http://www.ancientbathsny.com/aire-services/thermal-bath-with-aromatherapy-and-relaxing-30-minutes-massage/">
          Buy
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" class="hint">
          Hint
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="twitter" target="_blank">
              <span class="sprite twitter-alt">
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="facebook" target="_blank">
              <span class="sprite facebook-alt">
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="email">
              <span class="sprite email">
              </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here is the CSS that effects these image sizes:

```
.grid>ul>li {
    width: 247px;
    height: 250px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ddd;
          box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ddd;

}
```

I'm trying to center the image within the div and have the remaining space be white space:
[image]

I have tried various approaches such as:

```
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

But it is breaking their format on the page.

How do I get the desired behavior?

Comment: `.grid>ul>li` css: `background-color:white`?

Comment: Yes and     background-size: contain;

Comment: i don't see `background-color:white`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/q5y8twwx/3/) these lines should be in your `.grid>ul>li` css:

```
background-position: center center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-color:white;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: My answer is not actually applicable to OP, but I will leave it here in case someone is looking to center img elements as OP described in the title.

Wrap the following class around each img attribute:

```
.example-wrapper img {
   text-align:center;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   top: 50%;
   height: auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height:100%;
   position: relative;
   background-color: white;
}
```

extra option: "text-align:center;" above can be replaced with: 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content:center;

HTML

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
<img ....>
</div>
```